# How to create a JS script to apply to multiple Bootstrap modals on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to set up a page with 14 different modals. I previously set them up so they would all open normally, and they've worked. But I found something to let me make them draggable when opened. So I am trying to figure out how to do that, and finally got it to work, but only with one modal. My other modals do not open unless I change the code to reflect the name of that modal instead. Then the first modal doesn't work. Please tell me how to make the JavaScript code generalized for all of my modals.

Here is my script's code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){

$('#btn1').click(function() {
  // reset modal if it isn't visible
  if (!($('.modal.in').length)) {
    $('.modal-dialog').css({
      top: 110,
      left: 500
    });
  }
  $('#modal1').modal({
    backdrop: true,
    show: true
  });

  $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
  });
});


    }

</script>
```

Here is my modals' code, with only two modals instead of all 14:

```
<button id="btn1" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#modal1">Modal     1</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span     aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" >Modal 1</h4>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<button id="btn2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-target="#modal2">Modal 2</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span     aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" >Modal 2</h4>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I add another script after the one I have with a new "#btn" and/or a new "#modal", the latter one only works.

If I add a comma after the first "btn" and or "modal", it makes the two modals overlap.

Can someone help please? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to avoid setting all the modals in JavaScript (and assuming you don't want to add additional coding per each modal), could you just make them all toggle via HTML data attributes? Then you'd only need to initialize your draggable code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="Description of the page less than 150 characters">    
<title>Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal1Label">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Modal 1
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2Label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal2Label">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  Modal 2
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
<h1>Modals</h1>
<button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Modal 1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Modal 2</button>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/draggable/1.0.0-beta.8/draggable.js" integrity="sha256-IqgasFC+xodVUxVInsmbOaKvevIOjh9iqPUBPd2tyVs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
        handle: ".modal-header"
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, it works. I was having trouble figuring it out but I got it. Thanks!